# Outer artboard background turned white

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Somehow I manage to turn the outer BG to white (from the original dark gray). I have tried changing the preview mode (Pixel & Overprint) and to change it through the preferences menu, but it didn't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Things which can alter the pasteboard color....

**View Menu** > Outline, Overprint Preview, Hide/Show Artboards, Hide/Show Transparency Grid

**Preferences** > User Interface

Comment: And also `View > Show transparency grid` / `View > Hide transparency grid`. This is a little different since it replaces the solid color in both artboard(s) and pasteboard with a checkered pattern, but it's still one of those things users occasionally turn on and can't figure out what or why.

Comment: Well, if the transparency gris were on.. there'd be a checkerboard... so I consider that different.

Comment: Well different, but not so different. After all you are listing "Things which can alter the pasteboard color....".

Comment: True. `:)` But I imagine the question would be "Why am I seeing a checkerboard?" `:)`

Comment: I posted a comment because it wasn't an answer to the question, but rather a comment to your answer.

Comment: Okay, okay. Edited answer `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the options at **Preferences** → **User Interface**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you've accidentally hit **Alt+Shift+Ctrl+Y** which is the shortcut for **Overprint Preview** (View -> Overprint preview).

If you open the Separations Preview Palette (Window -> Separations Preview), you can see the checkbox at the top if you have it on or off.

[image: Separations Preview Palette]

Comment: This is the most likely cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and couldn't fix it with the preferences. But I found a solution: View -> Match Pasteboard to Theme Color :)

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. Sounds like you accidentally turned off your Artboards. Go to
View > Show Artboards
or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> will toggle on and off your artboards.